# Не получается создать копирование из файла в другой fstream

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream, файловый-ввод-вывод

Пытаюсь сделать копирование из одного файла, в другой.

```
void CopyFileUsingClasses(string origFileName, string copyFileName)
{
    fstream ifs(origFileName, ios::in);
    fstream ofs(copyFileName, ios::out);
}
```

Копирование не происходит.

Comment: А что вы ожидаете от кода в котором присутствует 2 разных fstream?

Comment: fstream ifs(origFileName, ios::in), ofs(copyFileName, ios::out); ?

Comment: И что? Как компилятор поймет что вы хотите скопировать данные из одного файла в другой??

Comment: Возможно вы можете продемонстрировать, как правильно  ? М ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy

Comment: Где вы тут увидели использование fstream ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если вы не хотите использовать новые возможности [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy), то можно дописать цикл чтения из одного файла и записи во второй. Да, и открывайте файлы как бинарные:

```
void CopyFileUsingClasses(const string& origFileName, const string& copyFileName)
{
    fstream ifs(origFileName, ios::in|ios::binary);
    fstream ofs(copyFileName, ios::out|ios::binary);
    const int sz = 64536;
    char buf[sz];
    for(;;)
    {
        ifs.read(buf,sz);
        if (ifs.gcount() == 0) break;
        ofs.write(buf,ifs.gcount());
    }
}
```

Простите уж, но то, что пытались сделать вы - это как та недалекая тетя, которой дали набрать текст, но все, что она сделала - это положила его на клавиатуру и думала, что этого достаточно...